# Can I use a document created in Illustrator as a template for generating reports in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, adobe-illustrator

I'd like to create reports in Access, but I want to use a PDF file I've designed in Illustrator. Can I somehow import this into the Report design view in Access, and then place my data fields in the appropriate locations over my PDF?

Answer (score 0):

No. I think the closest you'd get would be to convert the "background stuff" in the PDF document to an image file and then use that as the background image for the Access report.

Comment: Just tried that, but it seems to be shrinking my image a little. Do you know if there's a way to format it so that the image would fill the entire page?

Comment: @user346306 If you need precise alignment between the "background stuff" and the report data then it's going to be a bit "fiddly" in any case. In fact, any setting to automatically resize the image "so that [it] would fill the entire page" would probably make things worse since different printers would have different printable areas. You just need to experiment with the various properties of the background image to see if you can find a combination that works for you.